# WPF app: Entity Framework connection fails the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I've been using Entity Framework in a WPF database conversion app. I'm close to releasing the app but one thing has always bugged me -- the DB context always fails the very first time I try it.

Here's the error I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I know the instance is accessible because I'm running other things to it (and it connects just fine on all subsequent attempts).  So it's gotta be something in my configuration.

I have a default app.config for the app if one doesn't exist.  Using the app, users connect to their database instance and I save their settings to the config file using the ConfigurationManager class. I don't make any context calls until after I save the connection string.

Sample app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
     <add key="ImportUser" value="Admin" />
  </appSettings>
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="RockContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
          Initial Catalog=RockChMS;Integrated Security=True;
          MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=15"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

EF will connect:

- Once I restart the app using the correct app.config settings
- If I manually change the app.config before the program starts

**Is there a way to force EF to reload/refresh with the correct connection string after the program is started?**  I'm not calling anything with the context until after saving the modified connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force EF to reload configuration. But if you have correct connection string
you can use overloaded version of ObjectContext constructor which take connection string as parameter. For example, if BuroDBEntities - my Object Context class (public partial class BuroDBEntities : ObjectContext { ... }):

```
private BuroDBEntities Context = new BuroDBEntities(); //will use connection string from app configuration file

private BuroDBEntities Context = new BuroDBEntities(MyConnectionString); //will use connection string from parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that later tonight!

Answer (score 0):

After adding a constructor to my db object class, I realized that I wasn't checking the right section when refreshing the config.  The `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` method is case-sensitive and doesn't throw an error if it doesn't match.

Now I can save the config and refresh it before accessing the `DBContext`:

```
appConfig.Save( ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified );
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection( "connectionStrings" );
```